# How can I make an array of random numbers in a range without repeating numbers using a Do... while loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, do-loops

I'm creating a random number generator in JavaScript for lotto numbers. This numbers must be in a range of 1 - 50 and then sort them from smallest to largest. I already managed to do that using a do while loop but now I'm having some trouble for the repeated numbers.

I tried an If statement for compare the new number with the previous one, but the code is not working properly and the numbers are repeating

Here is my code block

```
const randomNumber = (minRange, maxRange) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRange - minRange + 1) + minRange);
};

// numbers added in order in lottoNumbers array
let lottoNumbers = [];
let num = 0;

do {
    num = randomNumber(1, 50);
    lottoNumbers.push(num);
    if(!lottoNumbers.includes(num)) {
        lottoNumbers.push(num);
    }
    lottoNumbers.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});
} while (lottoNumbers.length < 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` for that

```js
const randomNumber = (minRange, maxRange) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRange - minRange + 1) + minRange);
};


let ns = new Set()

while (ns.size < 6)
    ns.add(randomNumber(1, 50))

let result = [...ns].sort((a, b) => a - b)

console.log(...result)
```

Comment: Cool! thank you! I've been coding for a month so I didn't know the set object :)